# Mishloach Manos themes

Tags: minhag, purim, mishloach-manot

Some people have a [theme](https://www.google.com/search?q=shalach+manot+themes&espv=210&es_sm=93&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=tU8OU82-B-_KsQTNoIHIAw&ved=0CAkQ_AUoAQ&biw=1152&bih=775) to their Mishloach Manos. Is there any source that discusses Mishloach Manos themes, either pro or con?

Comment: I know that you meant this seriously, and I respect that, but wow, this would make for a fun Purim Torah question.

Comment: can you give an example?

Comment: Some people dress their kids in matching clothes on shabbos and yom tov. Some people have bar/bat mitzvah themes. I'm sure we cam make a long list.

Comment: Do you have any reason to think that thematic rather than non-thematic gifts are Judaism dependent, or that Judaism would have an opinion about this?

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what you mean by pros and cons. But I can tell you that people these days take the whole mishloach manot "creativity competition" a bit too far and get stressed over it for nothing.

I wrote an article about some [popular Mishloach Manot themes and ideas](http://amenvamen.com/mishloach-manot-basket-ideas-themes/).

The "main" themes of Mishloach manot are catered towards people's likes. I for example love tea, so I would be happy to get a tea themed mishloach manot.

But don't feel obligated to stuff the mishloach manot with junk. For example, a classy "made in Israel" gift box with a bottle of wine and olive oil is a wonderful mishloach manot gift IMO (see the made in Israel section in the article above)